# How to get Image id by image path?

Tags: magento2, php, image

Beginner at magento 2 and i want to know how can i get the **image id** using the **image path** "/3/4/341467-1_1.jpg", how can i do this programmatically? any help is apreciated.

Comment: Use this query SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `value` LIKE '%/3/4/341467-1_1.jpg%'